# How to use cones or triangular pyramids to construct a sphere

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

I have cones (or triangular pyramids) with the fixed central angle. How to use these cones (or triangular pyramids) to construct or fill out a sphere (like this: http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html) such that the origin of the cones (or triangular pyramids) sit at the origin of the sphere and the surface of cones (or triangular pyramids) overlap the spherical surface? Also, the cones (or triangular pyramids) would be better to put as compact as possible. It would be wonderful if the cones (or triangular pyramids) can be distributed as even as possible in the regions close to the equator of the sphere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: that will work only for specific angles and and number of the cones. You are better of creating such mesh with recursive subdivision of initial mesh see [my sphere triangulation in C++ example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214)

Comment: The icosahedron is a solution. What more do you need ? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeodesicDome.html