# Procedural generation of stars with skybox

Tags: c++, opengl, procedural-generation

I am attempting to procedurally generate a star-filled background in OpenGL.

The approach I am taking is to create a skybox with a cubemap texture. Each side of the cubemap texture essentially consists of a 2048x2048 black image with randomly selected texels set to White. Here is the result:

[image: Procedurally generated stars.] I'm not sure how obvious it is from the image, but when moving around a very distinct box shape can be made out as stars close to the edge of the box appear smaller and closer together. How can I prevent this? Do I need to abandon the skybox approach and use something like a skysphere instead?

EDIT: here is how I am mapping the cubemap onto the sky.

```
// Create and bind texture.
glGenTextures(1, &texture_);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture_);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> image = generateTexture(TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT,
                 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data());
}

// Set texture parameters.
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Here is the definition of the `generateTexture` function:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> Stars::generateTexture(GLsizei width, GLsizei height) {
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> image(static_cast<std::size_t>(3 * width * height));

    add_stars(image, NUM_STARS);

    return image;
}

void Stars::add_stars(std::vector<std::uint8_t>& image, unsigned int nStars) {
    std::default_random_engine eng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist(0, image.size() / 3 - 1);

    while (nStars--) {
        std::size_t index = 3 * dist(eng);

        image[index++] = 255;
        image[index++] = 255;
        image[index++] = 255;
    }
}
```

EDIT2: here is the draw function used to render the sky.

```
void Stars::draw(const Camera& camera) const {
    // Skybox will be rendered last. In order to ensure that the stars are rendered at the back of
    // the scene, the depth buffer is filled with values of 1.0 for the skybox -- this is done in
    // the vertex shader. We need to make sure that the skybox passes the depth te3t with values
    // less that or equal to the depth buffer.
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    program_.enable();

    // Calculate view-projection matrix and set the corresponding uniform. The view matrix must be
    // stripped of translation components so that the skybox follows the camera.
    glm::mat4 view       = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(camera.viewMatrix()));
    glm::mat4 projection = camera.projectionMatrix();

    glm::mat4 VP = projection * view;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(program_.uniformLocation("VP"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(VP));

    // Bind buffer objects and texture to current context and draw.
    glBindVertexArray(vao_);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo_);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture_);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, static_cast<GLsizei>(INDICES.size()), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                   reinterpret_cast<GLvoid *>(0));

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
    program_.disable();

    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
}
```

Comment: Why did you post a black rectangle?  Such a waste of memory / storage.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ? There should be stars in the image.

Comment: It's not clear how you're mapping the cubemap onto your sky. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @NicolBolas I've added some code samples. Please let me know if there is more that you would like to see.

Comment: "*here is how I am mapping the cubemap onto the sky*" No, that's how you're uploading data into OpenGL. I asked how you're mapping that cubemap onto whatever your sky happens to be.

Comment: Generating the stars on a cubes face might seem to be uniformly distributed, but once you add a perspective transformation, the shape of the cube will be obvious, as you are seeing. You'll need to do something more sophisticated and map them onto your cube.

Comment: @NicolBolas Forgive me, but I'm not certain what you mean by "mapping that cubemap onto whatever you sky happens to be". I added the stars' `draw` function in case that's what you meant.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to get a texture on a cube to look uniform. Generally speaking, you could do one of three things. 1) Make the cube more rectangular (in the XZ plane in a Y-up world) so the sky is closer and the corners are less obvious (assuming you have objects in the scene). 2) Cast rays in random directions using spherical coordinates and scale the size of the star by the inverse distance of the star. 3) I recommend using a spherical map instead of a cube map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **generate stars uniformly in some cubic volume**

   ```
   x=2.0*Random()-1.0; // <-1,+1>
   y=2.0*Random()-1.0; // <-1,+1>
   z=2.0*Random()-1.0; // <-1,+1>
   ```
2. **project them on unit sphere**

   So just compute the length of vector `(x,y,z)` and divide the coordinates by it.
3. **project the result onto the cube map**

   Each side of cube is defined by the plane so find intersection of ray casted from `(0,0,0)` through Cartesian star position and the planes. Take the intersection with shortest distance to `(0,0,0)` and use that as final star position.

   [image: sphere 2 cube]

**The implementation could be something like this OpenGL&C++ code:**

```
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    int i,n=10000;
    float a,b,x,y,z;
    //RandSeed=8123456789;
    n=obj.pnt.num;  // triangulated sphere point list

    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE);

    glPointSize(2.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        // equidistant points instead of random to test this
        x=obj.pnt[i].p[0];
        y=obj.pnt[i].p[1];
        z=obj.pnt[i].p[2];
/*
        // random star spherical position
        a=2.0*M_PI*Random();
        b=M_PI*(Random()-0.5);
        // spherical 2 cartessian r=1;
        x=cos(a)*cos(b);
        y=sin(a)*cos(b);
        z=       sin(b);
*/
        // redish sphere map
        glColor3f(0.6,0.3,0.0); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        // cube half size=1 undistort // using similarities like: yy/xx = y/x
             if ((fabs(x)>=fabs(y))&&(fabs(x)>=fabs(z))){ y/=x; z/=x; if (x>=0) x=1.0; else x=-1.0; }
        else if ((fabs(y)>=fabs(x))&&(fabs(y)>=fabs(z))){ x/=y; z/=y; if (y>=0) y=1.0; else y=-1.0; }
        else if ((fabs(z)>=fabs(x))&&(fabs(z)>=fabs(y))){ x/=z; y/=z; if (z>=0) z=1.0; else z=-1.0; }
        // bluish cube map
        glColor3f(0.0,0.3,0.6); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        }
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1.0);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

Looks like it works as it should here preview (of the blended sphere/cube map):

[image: preview]

Although it looks like there are holes but there are none (it is may be some blend error) if I disable the sphere map render then there are no visible holes or distortions in the mapping.

[image: cube map only]

The sphere triangulation `mesh obj` used to test this is taken from here:

- [Sphere triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214)

**[Edit1] yes there was a silly blending error**

I repaired the code ... but the problem persists anyway. does not matter this mapping is working as should here the updated code result:

[image: preview]

So just adapt the code to your texture generator ...

**[Edit2] Random stars**

```
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
int i;
float x,y,z,d;
RandSeed=8123456789;

glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE);

glPointSize(2.0);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
    // uniform random cartesian stars inside cube
    x=(2.0*Random())-1.0;
    y=(2.0*Random())-1.0;
    z=(2.0*Random())-1.0;
    // project on unit sphere
    d=sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z));
    if (d<1e-3) { i--; continue; }
    d=1.0/d;
    x*=d; y*=d; z*=d;
    // redish sphere map
    glColor3f(0.6,0.3,0.0); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
    // cube half size=1 undistort using similarities like: y/x = y'/x'
         if ((fabs(x)>=fabs(y))&&(fabs(x)>=fabs(z))){ y/=x; z/=x; if (x>=0) x=1.0; else x=-1.0; }
    else if ((fabs(y)>=fabs(x))&&(fabs(y)>=fabs(z))){ x/=y; z/=y; if (y>=0) y=1.0; else y=-1.0; }
    else if ((fabs(z)>=fabs(x))&&(fabs(z)>=fabs(y))){ x/=z; y/=z; if (z>=0) z=1.0; else z=-1.0; }
    // bluish cube map
    glColor3f(0.0,0.3,0.6); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
    }
glEnd();
glPointSize(1.0);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

Here Blend of booth (1000 stars):

[image: both]

And Here only the cube-map  (10000 stars)

[image: cube only]

**[Edit3] The Blend problem solved**

It was caused by Z-fighting and occasional changing of sign for some coordinates during the projection due to forgotten `fabs` here fixed code:

```
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    int i;
    float x,y,z,d;
    RandSeed=8123456789;

    glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
//  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE);

    glPointSize(2.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i=0;i<25000;i++)
        {
        // uniform random cartesian stars inside cube
        x=(2.0*Random())-1.0;
        y=(2.0*Random())-1.0;
        z=(2.0*Random())-1.0;
        // project on unit sphere
        d=sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z));
        if (d<1e-3) { i--; continue; }
        d=1.0/d;
        x*=d; y*=d; z*=d;
        // redish sphere map
        glColor3f(0.6,0.3,0.0); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        // cube half size=1 undistort using similarities like: y/x = y'/x'
             if ((fabs(x)>=fabs(y))&&(fabs(x)>=fabs(z))){ y/=fabs(x); z/=fabs(x); if (x>=0) x=1.0; else x=-1.0; }
        else if ((fabs(y)>=fabs(x))&&(fabs(y)>=fabs(z))){ x/=fabs(y); z/=fabs(y); if (y>=0) y=1.0; else y=-1.0; }
        else if ((fabs(z)>=fabs(x))&&(fabs(z)>=fabs(y))){ x/=fabs(z); y/=fabs(z); if (z>=0) z=1.0; else z=-1.0; }
        // bluish cube map
        glColor3f(0.0,0.3,0.6); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        }
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1.0);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

And here the Blend result finally the colors are as should be so the sphere and cube stars overlaps perfectly (white) while viewing from `(0,0,0)`:

[image]

Comment: Won't this method result in higher densities around the poles? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Comment: Echoing @Rhymoid comment's, using a random distribution for the spherical coordinates will result in a non-uniform distribution of stars. If you edit that part of your answer I will accept it.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html suggests it's as simple as generating three uniformly random values in `[-1, +1]` and projecting those points on the unit sphere. It might not be the fastest way to do it, but it sure is simple.

Comment: @AlessandroPower I find some time mood for it anyway see the edit I changed the spheric coordinate generation to generate uniform volumetric density instead.

Comment: @Rhymoid heh just have implemented the same independently

Comment: Couldn't you actually skip the calculation of the norm now?

Comment: @Rhymoid yes and no the change leads just to one less multiplication ( `3 -> 2` ) which does not change the performance at all on nowadays architectures as there are usually 3 pipelines at disposal ... the rest stays the same so there is no point ... it would just make the thing more difficult to understand btw I found out the Blend Problem will add edit in a minute (Z-fighting + silly mistake in projection (not so important for the result as the output is random).

Comment: @AlessandroPower finally solved the Blend problem see the [Edit3]

Comment: Right now, the comparisons make it more difficult to understand than [normalising with `d = fmax(fmax(fabs(x), fabs(y)), fabs(z))` right away](//math.stackexchange.com/a/71455/44190).