# Glowing objects in a raytracer? How it works?

Tags: graphics, raytracing

My raytracer has a point light source, it works as it should, illuminates the scene, but there is a problem, it is not visible, I would like to add glowing objects to the raytracer, for example a sphere that would look like the sun

[image: Sun]

I need any object to be able to glow whether it's a triangle (or a line?).

Which algorithm should I use?

Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you add sphere which emits light so once your ray hits it the light will be added/multiplied to the ray color ... the glow is done either by [atmospheric scattering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214) or just by some [semi transparent corona texture rendeed in another pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171880/2521214) ... games usually use also bloom filtering which I hate as its too slow and often ugly if overused