# what is meant by "mesh-based geometry". Mathematica uses this term and I've no idea what is meant

Tags: geometry, mesh

I was considering Mathematica for math software and they use the term mesh-based geometry. I don't know what it means. What little reference I found seems to imply that it used shapes such as triangles to generate other geometric structures. Is this the case? Can circular structures be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the context of yours but **Mesh** in **3D** graphics usually means  **BR** (boundary representation) which is set of polygons and or curved surfaces to cover whole surface of represented object + additional info like textures, normals, materials...

In case used engine does not support curvature then only planar polygons/primitives are used and curved structures are approximated (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214) ). This kind of object representation is most common as current gfx HW is optimized for it.

There are also other representations out there like analytical which represents model with set of equations (spheres, cylinders, cubes, etc) and describe the whole objects (also its inside). This is more suited for physical simulations and ray casting rendering.

Comment: Thank you. I believe you've answered my question. It's more or less what I figured. Thanks for the approximating example.